# get the center of the detected circle in an image / opencv / c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using this code to get the coordinate of the center of detected circles in the image.

```
vector<Vec3f> circles;

    cv::HoughCircles( t, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, t.rows/8, 200,         100, 0, 0 );

       for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ ){
            Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
            cout << "center" << center << endl;
        int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
            // circle center
            circle( t2, center, 3,  1 , -1, 8, 0 );        
             // circle outline
            circle( t2, center, radius,  1  , 3, 8, 0 );  
        }

        imshow( "circles", t2 );
```

I can detect the circles but did no get any result for cooardinate of the center points :(

thanks in advance.

after edition:

I added this line but the answer was zero.

```
cout << "number of circles found: " << circles.size() << endl;
```

images:
the first one is the main circle and the second one is after applying gaussian filter and HoughCircles function:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly your code Draws the circles but the

```
 cout << "center" << center << endl;
```

line does not give the correct output.

This is because `cv::Point` does not support direct output via `<<`.

Try to use:

```
 cout << "center" << center.x << ", " << center.y << endl;
```

If the Problem is that you can´t find any circles make sure that the `min_radius` and `max_radius` are choosen correctly. Try starting with a wide range of allowed radii and then try to choose a smaller Range until you get only the circles you want.

This Values can make a huge difference in the detection Ratio.

Comment: Thanks for the points. It seems that I have not detected the circle yet! I added one line into my code to check that something is detected or not..the answer was zero..
Please consider the edited post.

Comment: If you don´t get any circle but no error than try setting the min/max Radius to other values. See my edited Answer.

Comment: I tried with different numbers but still no result!should I find the correct radius by trial and error?

Comment: You can roughly measure it in your input image. The values are in `Pixel`, so you can just count the radius in your input and add +/- 10% to get your values for min- and max-radius.

Comment: It would also help if you add an image to your Question. Maybe Hough is the complete wrong way to go for your task.

Comment: @mailerdoimon: I added the images.

Comment: I can´t help you with values for the radius as the image is only a screenshot. But it looks very small. Which values (roughly) have you tried?

Comment: 10.1 as max and 9.9 as min.

Comment: Try something with a bigger range first, like 5 - 30 or something like that. If you find circles with that you can still narrow your range down.

Comment: I came up with a question! should I first apply a kind of edge detection alg to the image and then try HoughCircles function. yes? seems param1 and param2 are refered to canny edge detector! is that correct?

Comment: Hough Circle can work without Edge detection, but it is a good idea to try it. This could improve your result and could speed up the circle finding. Best thing would be to use `cv:canny` for a starter.